# Is it a good idea to store keys for resources in a static class?

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, resourcedictionary

In order to keep things organised and to keep track of all the resource names/keys used in a WPF/XAML project, I would like to store all the keys used in resource dictionaries in a static class filled with constants. I think I remember something about avoid string literals in code.

Something like:

```
<!-- itemtemplates.xaml -- a resource dictionary -->
<Style x:Key="{x:Static local:ResourceKeys.TaskItemItemTemplateKey}" ....>
    ....
</Style>
```

```
// ResourceKeys.cs
internal static class ResourceKeys {
    internal static object TaskItemItemTemplateKey {
       get { return __some_readonly_unique_key_object; }
    }
    internal static object SomeReallyUglyGradientBrushKey {
       get { return __some_other_unique_key; }
    }
}
```

Is this a good idea, considering that my project will perhaps reach over 1000 resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have that many resources you may want to split it up in several classes by type,  applicable area or whatever may make sense in your context. As for doing this in general: Why not? [`SystemColors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx) for example does that too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is that you have to enter twice each resource. Which is quite some work for 1000 items... The list of all resource names can be found easyly (resource.Keys). If you use a naming convention you can put some order in all that with little cost. Then you can perform some operations if you want to have, say, color resources : Select rs in Application.resources.Keys where rs.beginswith("Color").

Comment: I generate the static class automatically using a small script.

Comment: Nope, a small c# app that takes the keys of all resources and wraps them in static read only properties. I actually found that over 20% of my styles were unnecessary as they simply did the same thing.